# Unlink iPhone from a computer and switch to another

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro

I've just run into quite a big problem. I bought an iPhone, and the person who had bought it from the store for me had, being a nice person, helped me charge it.

Unfortunately, this meant that the iPhone is now synced to the PC that she has and not my MacBook Pro.

Is there any way to change this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If any apps or music came preloaded on the phone, make sure you have copies in your iTunes library before starting.

Plug in the iPhone and start syncing as you normally would.  iTunes will ask whether you'd like to wipe the phone and sync with this computer instead.  Just say yes.

Comment: ... I installed lots of apps and configured lots of things already. ... =\ Will everything restore back if I sync with iCloud afterwards? (Page settings and app configurations.)

Comment: If iTunes on both computers have the same account details, it shouldn't remove any apps (or their data) so long as they are in the MacBook's iTunes library.  If the computers use different accounts, I can't say what will happen.  Backup your iPhone on the PC before you try anything.